# Issue in Upgrading Magento2 from 2.2.8 to 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, product-page, thumbnail

I have upgraded magento 2 from 2.2.8 to 2.3.3. After upgrading, configurable product thumbnail images are not loading in the frontend. When changing the configurable variations, images are not changing in the product page.

Any help on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the pub/static folder except .htaccess, create a new static folder, put that .htaccess inside it, rm -rf var/cache/ generated var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ var/di run this in ssh, upgrade and redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a magento issue . Check this link  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19710 .
After the upgrade it  generates wrong hash on the cache .

If you run:
`bin/magento catalog:image:resize` , you will have the images back .

But this is not a proper solution . 
Suggestion :

- If you are enterprise you can make magento a ticket , they can
  provide a patch for that .
- Follow the github issue
  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19710  and make the  patch
  with their solutions .
- Upgrade the magento to 2.3.3 (not sure if it is fixed there , but they have made progress on catalog:image:resize command)

Comment: I have already run the command bin/magento catalog:image:resize. But no use. The issue is not fixed. I have already upgraded magento to 2.3.3

Comment: Check the github issue and try to modify the etc/view.xml based on their suggestions

Answer (score 0):

In magento2 backend, for swatch attribute, there is an option in the product attribute section, **Update Product Preview Image**. Enabling this option, images are changing in the frontend.

[image: Update Product Preview Image]